# SVGPAN - smooth transition zoom in effect

Tags: svg, css-transitions, css-transforms, svg-animate

Is it possible to have smooth zoom in effect on svg element?

I'm using svgpan script and understand that the zoom in is control by transform attribute.

> `transform="matrix(0.6,0,0,0.6,0,0)`

Can add 'transition' to make the transition smoothly when zoom in function is apply?

sample:
http://www.cyberz.org/projects/SVGPan/tiger.svg

idea smooth transition:
http://vectorflower.com/preview/smooth_zoom/

Answer (score 2):

You need to change:

```
<g id="viewport" transform="translate(200,200)">
```

Into something like that:

```
<g id="viewport" style="transition: transform 300ms linear;transform: translate(200px, 200px)">
```

And line ~143 of SVGPan.
Change:

`element.setAttribute("transform", s);`

Into:

```
element.style.transform = s;
```

And keep your $11 in pocket :)